# Roboguice causing strange exceptions

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, dependency-injection

In addition to my [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367699/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-trying-inject-fragment), which hasn't been answered yet, I'm still having lot of problems getting *Roboguice* up and running. My primary goal is to create a simple activity as well as a navigation drawer using a separate fragment with Roboguice, however nothing works at all.

What I tried:

- Roboguice version 2.0
- Roboguice version 3.0b-experimental
- Android w/ and without support libraries

Example code:

```
public class MainActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @InjectFragment
    private NavigationDrawerFragment _navigationDrawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _navigationDrawerFragment.init();
    }

}

public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends RoboFragment {}
```

I tried several things, including using a standard Fragment both from the support library and default Android SDK and implementing the injection methods myself as well as deriving from RoboFragment and what not.

Errors include:

- NullPointerException -> Sometimes RoboGuice doesn't inject anything. The _navigationDrawerFragment is null
- Type exceptions -> Sometimes RoboGuice tells me that my class doesn't derive from fragment
- etc.

Are there any examples where someone has succesfully used RoboGuice together with a navigation drawer (Android SDK, not Sherlock)?